# Bulk Insert for One to Many Relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, bulkinsert

I am trying for Bulk Insertion to One to many relation.

I have two classes:

```
public class Parent {

  public int Id {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public string Name {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public virtual ICollection<Child> Child {
    get;
    set;
  } = new List < Child > ();

}

public class Child {

  public int ChildId {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public virtual Parent Parent {
    get;
    set;
  }

}
```

When I did some R&D , I found we can use `IncludeGraph=true` for child table insertion.

```
public void BulkInsertAsync(IEnumerable<Parent> parent) {
  _context.BulkInsert<Parent>(parent.ToList(), options => options.IncludeGraph = true);
}
```

But the problem is that I am getting this error:

> Bulk Config does not contain definition for Include Graph

Am I missing any assembly reference?

Please help me out in this.

Comment: `BulkInsert`  is not a built-in EF function. You should add a tag for the third-party library you're using.

Comment: I had added EFCore.BulkExtensions nuget package also.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your EfCore.BulkExtensions package.  I had the same error on 3.1.6; upgrading to 3.6.3 allowed this to work.  Note that I also had to upgrade EFCore from 3.1.9 to 3.1.21